# Trying to cast and access PreviousPage values

Tags: asp.net

Hi I have the follwing code in my default.aspx:

```
<asp:Button AccessKey="Y" Height="25px" runat="server" ID="myButton"
    Text="hello" OnClick="clickit" PostBackUrl="~/Login/Default.aspx" />
```

and this code in my login default page code behind:

```
        Default prev = PreviousPage as Default;
        if (prev != null)
        {
            label1.Text = prev.GetText;
        }
```

But "prev" always is null, PreviousPage however is not null, when I add this derivitive to the login page:

```
<%@ PreviousPageType  VirtualPath="~/Default.aspx" %>
```

I get the error System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'ASP.default_aspx' to type 'Default'.

Anyone know whats going on? Why is prev set to null (and hence I can't access any of its values)?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to access content or functionality from other pages, I highly recommend you create interfaces that those pages implement. This will alleviate the problem of needing to cast to pages in the form of 'ASP.default_aspx'. Instead, you cast to an interface:

```
interface IPageWithBehaviorX
{
    string SomeStringValue { get; }

    void SomeOperation();
}

public class Default: IPageWithBehaviorX
{
    #region IPageWithBehaviorX Implementation
    // ... implement interface here
    #endregion 
}

public class PageThatNeedsAccessToPreviousIPageWithBehaviorX
{
    public void Page_Load(...)
    {
        IPageWithBehaviorX behaviorX = PreviousPage as IPageWithBehaviorX;
        if (behaviorX != null)
        {
            // Do something with interface
            var stringValue = behaviorX.SomeStringValue;

            behaviorX.SomeOperation();
        }

        // ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Does your `Default.aspx` page have a code-behind file?

If `Default.aspx` does have a code-behind file then the page class will usually be named `_Default` (with an underscore), not `Default`.

If `Default.aspx` doesn't have a code-behind file then I think that the page class will usually be named `ASP.default_aspx`. I suspect that this is what's happening in your case.

Try changing your code to one of the following and see what happens:

```
// either
ASP.default_aspx prev = PreviousPage as ASP.default_aspx;

// or
_Default prev = PreviousPage as _Default;
```